# Inconsistencies in page layout, CSS doesn't seem to be the issue?

Tags: css

I have a page here: http://dev.textcube.ch/oneandonly/index.php/galerie/shima/ where the subnav is ok using the style #vertmenu however on another page where the styling and page layout is identical the subnav is pushed to the left http://dev.textcube.ch/oneandonly/index.php/galerie/yuma/

(username: textcube  /  password: textcube3600 as a login will popup to access the pages)

```
#vertmenu {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 100%;
margin-top: 20px;
float: left; 
clear: both;
background: url(../images/subnav_bg.png) no-repeat;
height: 180px;
width: 195px !important;
padding: 40px 60px 60px 20px !important;
}
```

I've no idea of why this is, I've checked the CSS and inspected the elements in Chrome on both pages to see if there is any conflicts and I can't see anything.

Please can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second page, you include `view.css`, which has the following rule:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This removes the default padding on the `ul`. You just need to add the following declaration to your `#vertmenu .nav` rule:

```
padding-left: 40px;
```

Comment: +1 I switched between those pages 500 times looking for differences in css but didn't spot it. :(

Comment: @Asad I just looked at the computed style in devtools (you can click the disclosure arrow to see from where the final value came).

Answer (score 0):

By checking both the pages the extra thing in the second page is the presence of `margin:0;` `padding:0` via `view.css`. It causes the layout breaking.